# Hi, I created a lwc component to preview and download the pdf

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

I am creating a lightning web component to preview and download a pdf file it is working fine in lightning record page but when I am using same component on experience builder site page that preview option is not opening

```js
previewHandler(event){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: ‘standard__namedPage’,
        attributes:{
            pageName: ‘filePreview’,
        },
        state:{
            selectedRecordId: event.target.dataset.id
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to use the "comm__namedPage" type as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-page-reference-type#named-page-type-experience-builder-sites).

Comment: Hi @PhilW, can we redirect any url through comm__namedPage, suppose I have an url, if I gave the pageName-api page name, there is any attribute when we clicked on that page it should redirect to a url, is it possible?
I have a scenario so you can understand it better, I created a site page in digital experience site now what I want, through the navigation menu when I clicked on that page It will redirect to a url which is for the document in salesforce files but the doc should be latest version and latestmodified date.

Comment: Best to ask a new question.